# How to push XML data to Azure Service Bus using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, azure, azureservicebus

I have following code to push xml data to Azure service bus but it is pushing message as a string not as xml. Is there anything I am missing to pass? Please suggest me.

```
    const xml = `<p>This is <b>some</b> content.</content></p>`;
    const message = {
        body: xml,
        contentType: 'application/xml; charset="utf-8"',
    };
    try {
        await sender.sendMessages(message);
        await sbClient.close();
    } finally {
        await sbClient.close();
    }
```

I tried to set following content types:

1. "application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8"
2. "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'"
3. "application/xml; charset='utf-8'"
4. "application/xml"

Answer (score 1):

When you set [contentType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/service-bus/servicebusmessage?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-service-bus-servicebusmessage-contenttype) of the message then it defines the content type of the message and doesn't actually convert your string message content to the desired format. Whatever message content you define in the body it will be passed. If you want your message to be in XML format, then please convert the message content to XML.

Comment: Then I think I have another question. How to convert this XML string into XML object to pass in Azure service bus body?